After joining 100ms room for audio call getting remote peer as null
In flutter app I am using hmssdk_flutter: ^1.10.2 for creating audio call feature. But After joining audio call I am getting remote peer as null. And Both local and remote user having role of 'speaker'.
For your reference I have given below my code:                                                          file name - call_user_data_store.dart
    class CallUserDataStore extends ChangeNotifier
    implements HMSUpdateListener, HMSActionResultListener {
  HMSVideoTrack? remoteVideoTrack;
  HMSTrack? localAudioTrack;
  HMSVideoTrack? localTrack;
  bool _disposed = false;
  HMSPeer? localPeer,remotePeer;
  HMSSpeaker? activeSpeaker;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _disposed = true;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void notifyListeners() {
    if (!_disposed) {
      super.notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  @override
  void onChangeTrackStateRequest(
      {required HMSTrackChangeRequest hmsTrackChangeRequest}) {}

  void onError({required HMSException error}) {}

  void leaveRoom() async {
    //Calling leave method to leave the room
    SdkInitializer.hmssdk.leave(hmsActionResultListener: this);
  }

  

  @override
  void onJoin({required HMSRoom room}) {
    for (HMSPeer each in room.peers!) {
      if (each.isLocal) {
        //print("local peer - ${localPeer!.name}");
        localPeer = each;
        break;
      }else{
        remotePeer = each;
        break;
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void onMessage({required HMSMessage message}){
  }

  // Notify listeners when remotePeer changes
  HMSPeer? get getRemotePeer => remotePeer;
  
  HMSSpeaker? get getActiveSpeaker => activeSpeaker;

  @override
  void onPeerUpdate({required HMSPeer peer, required HMSPeerUpdate update}) {
    switch (update) {
      case HMSPeerUpdate.peerJoined:
           //print("peer name - ${peer.name}");
           if (!peer.isLocal) {
             //print("remote peer 1");
             remotePeer = peer;
           }else{
            localPeer = peer;
           }
           //print("remote peer name - $remotePeer");
        break;
      case HMSPeerUpdate.peerLeft:
           if(!peer.isLocal){
             leaveRoom();
             remotePeer = null;
             navigationKey.currentState!.pop();
           }else{
             leaveRoom();
             localPeer = null;
             navigationKey.currentState!.pop();
           }
        break;
      case HMSPeerUpdate.roleUpdated:
        break;
      case HMSPeerUpdate.metadataChanged:
        break;
      case HMSPeerUpdate.nameChanged:
        break;
      case HMSPeerUpdate.defaultUpdate:
        break;
      case HMSPeerUpdate.networkQualityUpdated:
        break;
      default:  
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void onReconnected() {}

  @override
  void onReconnecting() {}

  @override
  void onRemovedFromRoom(
      {required HMSPeerRemovedFromPeer hmsPeerRemovedFromPeer}) {}

  @override
  void onRoleChangeRequest({required HMSRoleChangeRequest roleChangeRequest}) {}

  @override
  void onRoomUpdate({required HMSRoom room, required HMSRoomUpdate update}) {
  }

  @override
  void onTrackUpdate(
      {required HMSTrack track,
      required HMSTrackUpdate trackUpdate,
      required HMSPeer peer}) {
    switch (trackUpdate) {
      case HMSTrackUpdate.trackAdded:
        if (track.kind == HMSTrackKind.kHMSTrackKindAudio) {
          if (peer.isLocal) localAudioTrack = track;
        } else if (track.kind == HMSTrackKind.kHMSTrackKindVideo) {
          if (peer.isLocal) {
            localTrack = track as HMSVideoTrack; 
          } else {
            remoteVideoTrack = track as HMSVideoTrack;
          }
        }
        break;
      case HMSTrackUpdate.trackRemoved:
        if (track.kind == HMSTrackKind.kHMSTrackKindAudio) {
          if (peer.isLocal) localAudioTrack = null;
        } else if (track.kind == HMSTrackKind.kHMSTrackKindVideo) {
          if (peer.isLocal) {
            localTrack = null;
          } else {
            remoteVideoTrack = null;
          }
        }
        break;
      case HMSTrackUpdate.trackMuted:
        if (track.kind == HMSTrackKind.kHMSTrackKindAudio) {
          if (peer.isLocal) localAudioTrack = track;
        } else if (track.kind == HMSTrackKind.kHMSTrackKindVideo) {
          if (peer.isLocal) {
            localTrack = track as HMSVideoTrack;
          } else {
             remoteVideoTrack = track as HMSVideoTrack;
          }
        }
        break;
      case HMSTrackUpdate.trackUnMuted:
        if (track.kind == HMSTrackKind.kHMSTrackKindAudio) {
          if (peer.isLocal) localAudioTrack = track;
        } else if (track.kind == HMSTrackKind.kHMSTrackKindVideo) {
          if (peer.isLocal) {
            localTrack = track as HMSVideoTrack;
          } else {
            remoteVideoTrack = track as HMSVideoTrack;
          }
        }
        break;
      case HMSTrackUpdate.trackDescriptionChanged:
        break;
      case HMSTrackUpdate.trackDegraded:
        break;
      case HMSTrackUpdate.trackRestored:
        break;
      case HMSTrackUpdate.defaultUpdate:
        break;
      default:  
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
  


  @override
  void onUpdateSpeakers({required List<HMSSpeaker> updateSpeakers}) {
    for (HMSSpeaker each in updateSpeakers) {
      if (!each.peer.isLocal){
        activeSpeaker = each;
        break;
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void startListen() {
    SdkInitializer.hmssdk.addUpdateListener(listener: this);
  }

  @override
  void onAudioDeviceChanged(
      {HMSAudioDevice? currentAudioDevice,
      List<HMSAudioDevice>? availableAudioDevice}) {
    // TODO: implement onAudioDeviceChanged
  }

  @override
  void onHMSError({required HMSException error}) {
    // TODO: implement onHMSError
  }

  @override
  void onPeerListUpdate(
      {required List<HMSPeer> addedPeers,
      required List<HMSPeer> removedPeers}) {
    // TODO: implement onPeerListUpdate
  }

  @override
  void onSessionStoreAvailable({HMSSessionStore? hmsSessionStore}) {
    // TODO: implement onSessionStoreAvailable
  }

  @override
  void onException(
      {required HMSActionResultListenerMethod methodType,
      Map<String, dynamic>? arguments,
      required HMSException hmsException}) {
    switch (methodType) {
      case HMSActionResultListenerMethod.leave:
        //print("Leave room error ${hmsException.message}");
        break;
      case HMSActionResultListenerMethod.hlsStreamingStarted:
        //print("HLS Stream start error ${hmsException.message}");
        break;

      case HMSActionResultListenerMethod.hlsStreamingStopped:
        //print("HLS Stream stop error ${hmsException.message}");
        break;

      case HMSActionResultListenerMethod.startAudioShare:
        //print("Audio share error ${hmsException.message}");
        break;
      case HMSActionResultListenerMethod.switchCamera:
        //print("Switch camera error ${hmsException.message}");
        break;
      default:  
    }
  }

  @override
  void onSuccess(
      {required HMSActionResultListenerMethod methodType,
      Map<String, dynamic>? arguments}) {
    switch (methodType) {
      case HMSActionResultListenerMethod.hlsStreamingStarted:
        //If start HLS streaming call is successful, you'll get an update in onRoomUpdate
        //Documentation: https://www.100ms.live/docs/flutter/v2/how--to-guides/record-and-live-stream/hls#how-to-display-hls-stream-and-get-hls-state-in-room
        //print("HLS Stream started successfully");
        break;

      case HMSActionResultListenerMethod.hlsStreamingStopped:
        //isLive = false;
        //print("HLS Stream stopped successfully");
        break;

      case HMSActionResultListenerMethod.leave:
        SdkInitializer.hmssdk.removeUpdateListener(listener: this);
        SdkInitializer.hmssdk.destroy();
        notifyListeners();
        //print("Room left successfully");
        break;
      default:  
    }
  }
}

file name - home_screen.dart
    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  TextEditingController userNameController =  TextEditingController(); 
  bool res = false;
  late CallUserDataStore _dataStore;

  static Future<bool> getPermissions() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) return true;

    await Permission.microphone.request();
    //await Permission.bluetoothConnect.request();

    while ((await Permission.microphone.isDenied)) {
      await Permission.microphone.request();
    }
    // while ((await Permission.bluetoothConnect.isDenied)) {
    //   await Permission.bluetoothConnect.request();
    // }
    return true;
  }
  
  //Handles room joining functionality
  Future<bool> joinRoom(
      {String role = "speaker",
      String? userName,
    }) async {
    //Calling build method here
    await SdkInitializer.hmssdk.build();

    //The join method initialize sdk,gets auth token,creates HMSConfig and helps in joining the room
    bool isJoinSuccessful = await JoinService.join(
        SdkInitializer.hmssdk,userName!,
        role: role);
    if (!isJoinSuccessful) {
      return false;
    }
     _dataStore = CallUserDataStore();
    //Here we are attaching a listener to our DataStoreClass
    _dataStore.startListen();
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,//Colors.black,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: userNameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                     hintText: "Enter user name",
                     enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                     ),
                     focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                     errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                     border: OutlineInputBorder() 
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20,),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ))),
                onPressed: () async => {
                  res = await getPermissions(),
                  if (res) {
                    await joinRoom(
                      role: "speaker",
                      userName: userNameController.text
                    ).then((isJoined){
                        if(isJoined){
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (_) => ListenableProvider.value(
                                      value: _dataStore,
                                      child:const PhoneCallScreen())));
                        }
                    })
                  }
                },
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    'Join Audio Room',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

file name - phone_call_screen.dart
    class PhoneCallScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PhoneCallScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<PhoneCallScreen> createState() => _PhoneCallScreenState();
}

class _PhoneCallScreenState extends State<PhoneCallScreen>{
  
  bool isLocalAudioOn = true;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final remotePeer = context.select<UserDataStore,HMSPeer?>((user) => user.getRemotePeer);   
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        context.read<CallUserDataStore>().leaveRoom();
        Navigator.pop(context);
        return true;
      },
      child: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Consumer<CallUserDataStore>(
                builder: (context, userDataStore, _) {
                  final remotePeer = userDataStore.getRemotePeer;
                  // if(remotePeer!=null && remotePeer.peerId == userDataStore.getActiveSpeaker?.peer.peerId){
                  //    print("active speaker audio level - ${userDataStore.getActiveSpeaker?.audioLevel}");
                  // }
                  return (remotePeer != null)
                      ? peerTile(
                          const Key("audio"), // Key(remotePeerVideoTrack?.trackId ?? "" "mainVideo"),
                          remotePeer,
                          context,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)
                      : Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          child: const Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Waiting for other peer to join",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 10),
                              CircularProgressIndicator(
                                strokeWidth: 2,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                },
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          context.read<CallUserDataStore>().leaveRoom();
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration:
                              BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.red.withAlpha(60),
                              blurRadius: 3.0,
                              spreadRadius: 5.0,
                            ),
                          ]),
                          child: const CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 25,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            child: Icon(Icons.call_end, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => {
                           SdkInitializer.hmssdk.toggleMicMuteState(),
                          if (mounted)
                            {
                              setState(() {
                                isLocalAudioOn = !isLocalAudioOn;
                              })
                            }
                        },
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 25,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                          child: Icon(
                            isLocalAudioOn ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_off,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}

please help me to solve above issue.
Thanks and Regards
